# Setting a Paper Size into C# print

Tags: c#, printing, size, readonly, page-size

I have a project which requires me to print big data on paper , width f the paper in 3.3inch but the height can be as small aS 0.8 inch up to 100 inches base on the data(label printer)

I have been told that printDialog must NOT be accessible to the user  so I decided to set the setting by hardcoding it and calculating the height of the paper by the app .

after putting PrintDocument into watch I have found that page size can be set by these options(probably if I am not wrong)

```
        doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.kind = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.Custom;
        doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 500;
```

now the problem is if the paper kind is not custom I will get an exception which I need to change doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.kind to custom , however, I get that paper kind is read-only

how can I change the paper type to custom in PrintDoc?

Comment: what is the data? I would assume you have a pdf or something where you just say print and all knowledge about paper is in the input pdf-file.

Comment: it actully is a Bitmap which i obtain by converting text to bit map and putting some splitter , it looks like invoice sort of . if the user want 2 labels i give them a paper of 3.3*0.8 if they want 100 labels (each label has a unique number so No COpy accepted) . i giv them like 3.3in * 80 inch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have come across a post and with some modification, I got the below code which works perfectly for my purpose

```
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();
if (print.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
   print.Document = doc;
}
float height = (((float)0.763 * printNumbers) + ((float)0.098 * (printNumbers - (float)1))) * 100;
PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("MY_PAGE_SIZE_NME", 333, (int)height);
paperSize.RawKind = 256;
doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
doc.Print();
```

the numbers in Height are customized to my own need, you may wanna change and calculate your if needed